# How much additional fertilizer should I add to a vegetable garden?

Tags: vegetables, soil

I'm beginning to prepare the soil for my vegetable garden.  Overall, it's clay-type soil, and I've added some of the leaves from last fall and the grass clippings from last year into the soil and tilled it in.

Should I add any kind of fertilizer or manure?  How can I tell what the soil needs for prime growing conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can really go wrong with adding manure. Since this is a new garden in clay soil, you'll benefit from adding organic matter (the leaves and grass clippings are a good start), and composted manure will boost your soil fertility.

However, the only real way to know how how much fertilizer you should add is to get your **soil tested**. Your profile says you live in Utah. [This document (pdf)](http://extension.usu.edu/htm/publications/file=5851) from the Utah State University Cooperative Extension describes how to take a soil sample. It says they charge $10 for a standard test, which is a very reasonable price.